# Foam from the water on the shore does not work correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I made foam from the water on the shore in shader graph, but if I turn on depth write on force enabled, then the foam will not work correctly in my game mode

[image: [enter image description here]()]

[image: [[enter image description here]()]]

[image: [[enter image description here]()]

[image: [enter image description here]()]

I use URP

If I turn on depth write on force disabled, the foam will work fine, but at the same time there is a bug with water

[image: [enter image description here]()]

Comment: @DivyanshuShekhar ...? Wrong thread?